# You're in-between a circle and a line in a certain envelope of mine. Who are you?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

You're in-between a circle and a line, in a certain envelope of mine.

Added to laughter you'll be glad, but too many of you will silence add.

Who are you?

Comment: Upvoted after the edit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Could it be

> the letter P?

*You're in-between a circle and a line, in a certain envelope of mine.*

> P comes in between O (a circle) and Q (a queue or line). The "in a certain envelope" bit is a hint towards looking at *letters*.

*Added to laughter you'll be glad, but too many of you will silence add.*

> HA (laughter) + PEE (p) gives HAPPY (glad). The "silence" part refers to P for pianissimo in music.

Comment: and 'p' for postcard?

Comment: the silence part could be in like music, pp = pianissimo = super soft or ppp = pianississimo = super duper soft/practically silent?

Comment: Or the silent P in "bath".

Comment: *in a certain envelope of mine* perhaps because P is a *letter?*

Comment: indubitablee and ETHproductions are correct. Seems like no one noticed the subtle clue in the first words.

Answer (score 6):

I am

> A Smile

You're in-between a circle and a line, in a certain envelope of mine.

> Half of a circle, or a bent line, in various states... in an envelope of yours, your mouth.

Added to laughter you'll be glad

> Because we're all smiling, yo.

but too many of you will silence add.

> Because smiling too much is creepy.

Answer (score 2):

Based on idea by rand al'thor:

> Letter M

Circle and line:

> These are O and I. M is between (together with J K L and N). Envelope refers to Mail.

Added to laughter, silence:

> No idea for "glad". MMMMMMMM = silence (mostly).

Comment: Ha (laughter) + m = Ham, which is kind of a meme from a Heroes of the Storm stream from I think last year, where an announcer really enthousiastically started screaming "they're going ham on the core". Might have to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

You're in-between a circle and a line, in a certain envelope of mine.

> A Sinusoid.  A circular form can be parametrically mapped as a trigonometric identity over a range of angles (a range can be referred to as an envelope in graphing terminology).

Added to laughter you'll be glad, but too many of you will silence add.

> **S**laughter - too many people being... silenced?

Who are you?

> The letter S.  The shape of the letter is a sinusoid.

(I'm really not convinced but I thought it was a fun thing to think about, but the "glad" part threw me off the scent to be honest).

Answer (score 2):

Possible answer:

> Cocaine

*You're in-between a circle and a line, in a certain envelope of mine.*

> You could have an envelope of cocaine in the middle of a line of cocaine and a top down view of a rolled up 100 dollar bill (circle).

*Added to laughter you'll be glad, but too many of you will silence add.*

> From what I have seen in movies, cocaine can provide a high that goes along with laughter. Too much of it and you may die (silence).

*Disclaimer:*

> I don't do cocaine and I don't think you should either.

Answer (score 0):

I am

> a pilot at an air show

*You're in-between a circle and a line, in a certain envelope of mine.*

> I'm constantly pushing the [flight envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_envelope) in the air — between the ground, where the earth looks flat like a line, and outer space, where it looks like a circle.

*Added to laughter you'll be glad*

> If everything goes well, people will laugh with joy, and I'll be glad of that.

*but too many of you will silence add.*

> Sometimes airplanes crash at these shows.